# How to move data from one frame to another?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to create a GUI using Neatbeans ,, 
it has two Frames .. Frame1 and Fram2
Frame1 Got :

2 jTextFields and 1 jButton

if i enter the filedst in jTextField(1 & 2) and i Click "Done" Button .. 
Frame2 should appear and it sholud display the id and name from Frame1 (jTextField (1&2) )

inside the jLabel(1&2)..of Frame2

the following code is In the Button :

```
    int id= Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    String name=jTextField2.getText();
    Frame2 f2=new Frame2();
    f2.setVisible(true);
```

and i have created a over loaded constructor in Frame2 as :

```
public Frame2(int id, String name) {
    initComponents();
    jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(id));
    jLabel2.setText(name);
}
```

when i click the button it moves to Frame2 but it Doesn't show the data (id & name )???

Any one can Help ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in next you create one constructor(`public Frame2(int id , String name)`), but you call another `Frame2 f2=new Frame2();`. Replace `Frame2 f2=new Frame2();` to `Frame2 f2=new Frame2(id, name);` And it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your attempt at this, but you could do something like this. It should run, just add the necessary imports. Maybe this is something you are trying to do.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private String name = "ASN";
    private int id = 1;

    private JButton button = new JButton("Open");
    private OtherFrame oFrame = new OtherFrame();

    public MainFrame(){
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                oFrame.setVisible(true);   
            }
        });
        add(oFrame);
        oFrame.setVisible(false);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    private OtherFrame extends JFrame {
        private JLabel label = new JLabel();
        private JButton button1 = new JButton("show");

        public OtherFrame(){
            add(label);
            add(button1);

            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    label.setText(name + " " + ID);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```